# How to get rid of Manipulate in the given code? and use two colors and black points at the conjunctions?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, color, plot-themes

I am using the code below (from this [link](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/demonstrations/CairoTiling-source.nb)) and the result is the pentagonal tiling on the left-hand side.

**Questions:**

1. > How can I get rid of `Manipulate` in the code and obtain only the fixed given plot?
2. > Is it possible to use two colors for the tiling edges? something like the picture on the right-hand side?
3. > How can I add black points at all conjunctions (like the right picture)?

[image]

```
n := 10;
Manipulate[
 If[swpaintold != swpaint,
  If[swpaint, swtetrad = False];
  swpaintold = swpaint
  ];
 
 If[swtetrad,
  swpaint = False;
  pol1 = {{0, 0}, {1, -e}, {2, 0}, {3, e} , {3, 2 - e} , {2, 
     2}, {2 + e, 3}, {4 - e, 3},
    {4, 4}, {3, 4 + e}, {3, 6 - e}, {4, 6}, {4 - e, 7}, {2 + e, 
     7}, {2, 8}, {1, 8 - e},
    {0, 8}, {-e, 7}, {0, 6}, {1, 6 + e}, {2, 6}, {2 - e, 5}, {2, 
     4}, {1, 4 - e},
    {1, 2 + e}, {0, 2}, {e, 1}, {0, 0}};
  
  pol2 = {{0, 0}, {1, e}, {2, 0}, {2 + e, 1} , {2, 2} , {1, 
     2 - e}, {0, 2}, {e, 3},
    {0, 4}, {1, 4 + e}, {1, 6 - e}, {2, 6}, {2 - e, 7}, {2, 8}, {1, 
     8 + e}, {0, 8},
    {-1, 8 - e}, {-1, 6 + e}, {0, 6}, {-e, 5}, {-2 + e, 5}, {-2, 
     4}, {-1, 4 - e}, {-1, 2 + e},
    {-2, 2}, {-2 + e, 1}, {-e, 1}, {0, 0}};
  
  pol3 = {{0, 0}, {1, -e}, {2, 0}, {2 - e, 1} , {2, 2} , {3, 
     2 - e}, {4, 2}, {4 + e, 1},
    {6 - e, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, e}, {8, 0}, {8 + e, 1}, {8, 2}, {8 - e, 
     3}, {6 + e, 3},
    {6, 2}, {5, 2 + e}, {5, 4 - e}, {4, 4}, {4 - e, 3}, {2 + e, 
     3}, {2, 4}, {1, 4 - e},
    {1, 2 + e}, {0, 2}, {e, 1}, {0, 0}};
  ];
 
 Graphics[{
   col1,
   Thickness[thick1],
   Opacity[op1],
   Table[{
     Translate[
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, -e}, {2, 0}, {2 - e, 1} , {e, 1} , {0, 
         0}}], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{{e, 1} , {0, 2}, {1, 2 + e}, {2, 2}, {2 - e, 1}, {e, 
         1}}], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{{0, 2}, {-e, 3}, {0, 4}, {1, 4 - e} , {1, 2 + e}, {0, 
         2} }], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{ {1, 4 - e}  , {2, 4}, {2 + e, 3}, {2, 2}, {1, 2 + e}, {1,
          4 - e}}], {i*4, j*4}],
     
     Translate[
      Line[{{2, 0}, {3, e}, {3, 2 - e}, {2, 2} , {2 - e, 1} , {2, 
         0}} ], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{{3, e} , {3, 2 - e}, {4, 2}, {4 + e, 1}, {4, 0}, {3, 
         e}}], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{{3, 2 - e}, {2, 2}, {2 + e, 3}, {4 - e, 3} , {4, 2}, {3, 
         2 - e}}], {i*4, j*4}],
     Translate[
      Line[{ {2 + e, 3}  , {4 - e, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 4 + e}, {2, 
         4}, {2 + e, 3} }], {i*4, j*4}]
     }, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}
    ]
   
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 13}, {0, 13}}, ImageSize -> {500, 500}    
  ], (* end Graphics *)
 
 {{e, .5, "morph"}, 0, 1, ImageSize -> Small}
 ,
 
 (*  here we list the variants :  *)(* \n = linefeed *)
 (*{{ch,1,"tetrad"},Range[chmax], ControlType\[Rule]PopupMenu},*)
 
 Delimiter,
 Style["Cairo tiling:"],
 {{col1, Red, "outline"}, Red, ColorSlider, ImageSize -> Small, 
  AppearanceElements -> "Swatch"},
 {{op1, 1, "opacity"}, 0, 1, ImageSize -> Small},
 {{thick1, .0005, "thickness"}, 0.0001, .02, ImageSize -> Small},
 {{swpaint, False, "color tiles"}, {True, False}},
 {{swtetrad, True, "polycairo tetrad"}, {True, False}}
 ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily using my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). You will need to install the package first. If you end up using it extensively for your work, a [citation](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM#-citing) would be very much appreciation.

Load the package:

```
<<IGraphM`
```

Create a mesh using this pentagonal tiling:

```
mesh = IGLatticeMesh["CairoPentagonal", {5, 5}]
```

[image]

Convert the mesh to a graph and add the base styling:

```
graph = IGMeshGraph[mesh, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack", 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Green]]
```

Now comes the most involved part. We want to colour horizontal or vertical edges in red.

```
horizontalOrVerticalQ[{p1_, p2_}] := Mod[ArcTan @@ (p1 - p2), Pi/2] < 10^-5
IGEdgeMap[If[horizontalOrVerticalQ[#], Red, {}] &, 
 EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexCoordinates], graph]
```

[image]

A short explanation of how this works:

`IGEdgeMap[f, prop -> extractor, graph]` will map the function `f` over the values `extractor[graph]` and store the result in the edge property `prop`. In this case, the extractor `IGEdgeVertexProp` takes a vertex property, and for each edge it produces a pair of values corresponding to the edge endpoints. We use the `VertexCoordinates` property, i.e. the coordinate of each vertex. Thus the result will be of the form `{p1, p2}` for each edge, where `p1` and `p2` are the coordinates of endpoints. You can look at the complete result like so: `IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexCoordinates][graph]`. Finally we determine if the point pair lines on a horizontal or vertical line and colour accordingly.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. It is marvelous.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem in loading the package, Mathematica says `Get::noopen: Cannot open IGraphM`.`

Comment: @MsMath You need to install the package. Check the link to the package and follow the instructions.

Comment: I realized the link was broken. I fixed it now.